# How to get dates from today to sunday in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to have a function which displays the dates from today to sunday. So my function is like this:

```
dateSets() {
            const currentDate = new Date();
            const today = new Date();
            const sunday = new Date(
                currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - currentDate.getDay() + 7)
            );
            const dates = [];
            for (let i = today.getDate(); i <= sunday.getDate(); i++) {
                dates.push(today);
                today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
            }
            console.log(dates);
            const tomorrow = new Date(today);
            tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
            console.log(tomorrow);
        }
```

But the output is like this:

```
[Mon Aug 09 2021 14: 16: 38 GMT + 0200(Central European Summer Time),
 Mon Aug 09 2021 14: 16: 38 GMT + 0200(Central European Summer Time),
 Mon Aug 09 2021 14: 16: 38 GMT + 0200(Central European Summer Time),
 Mon Aug 09 2021 14: 16: 38 GMT + 0200(Central European Summer Time),
 Mon Aug 09 2021 14: 16: 38 GMT + 0200(Central European Summer Time),
 Mon Aug 09 2021 14: 16: 38 GMT + 0200(Central European Summer Time),
 Mon Aug 09 2021 14: 16: 38 GMT + 0200(Central European Summer Time)]

Table.vue:203 Tue Aug 10 2021 14:16:38 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

So, it should display from today which is 2nd of August but it displays wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: WHat if today is a sunday?

Comment: I want so show only sunday.

Comment: You push and update only `today`. The array contains multiple references to the same instance.

Comment: @Dave Newton I didnt udnerstand though. How?

Comment: How what? `today` is a `Date`. It gets pushed into `dates`. So (say) you have `[Date(8-1)]`. Then you `setDate` on it. You now have `[Date(8-2)]`. Then you push it into `dates`, now you have `[Date(8-2), Date(8-2)]`. Then you `setDate`, now you have `[Date(8-3), Date(8-3)]`, etc. If you want to add a *new* date, e.g., a different one, you must create that `Date`.

Comment: Do `dates.push(new Date(+today))` so you get a new *Date* at each *push* rather than multiple references to the same *Date*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactored you code:

```js
function dateSets() {
  const today = new Date();
  const sunday = new Date();
  sunday.setDate(sunday.getDate() - sunday.getDay() + 7);
  const dates = [];

  if (today.getDay() === 0) {
    dates.push(new Date(+today));
  } else {
    while (sunday >= today) {
      dates.push(new Date(+today));
      today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
    }
  }
  return dates;
}

console.log(dateSets());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%;}
```

Comment: What will happen for `const diff = sunday.getDate() - today.getDate();` if Sunday is say 5 Sep and today is 30 Aug?

Comment: @RobG, thank you for your suggestion, I have handled this case.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
dates.push(today);
```

you push a *reference* to *today* into the *dates* array so all the references in the array point to the same date. All you need to do is copy *today* and push that into the array:

```
dates.push(new Date(+today));
```

Also:

```
for (let i = today.getDate(); i <= sunday.getDate(); i++)
```

doesn't work when *sunday* is in the next month, e.g. if *today* is Mon 30 Aug 21 and *sunday* is Sun 5 Sep, so the test fails on the first iteration and you'll get an empty *dates* array.

With a couple of optimisations:

```js
function dateSets(date = new Date()) { // Allow passing a date
  let currentDate = new Date(+date);
  currentDate.setHours(0,0,0,0); // for convenience
  let today = new Date(+currentDate);
  let sunday = new Date(
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - currentDate.getDay() + 7)
  );
  let dates = [];
  while (sunday >= today) {       // While is simpler in this case
    dates.push(new Date(+today)); // Push copies into the array
    today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return dates;
}

// Check ove month end
console.log(
  dateSets(new Date(2021,7,30)).map(d=>d.toDateString())
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can calculate the dates for the current week by finding the offset based on the current day of the week and setting a start date *n*-numbers of days before.

**Edit:** I added a "day of week" offset so you can grab date starting with the current day of the week.

```js
const DAY_IN_MILLIS = 864e5;

const defaultOptions = {
  weekdayOffset: 0,
  startOfWeek: false,
  includeSunday: false
};

const getDatesForCurrentWeek = (date, options) => {
  const
    result = [],
    opts = { ...defaultOptions, ...options },
    offset = (options.startOfWeek ? date.getDay() : opts.weekdayOffset) * DAY_IN_MILLIS;
  let startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
  startDate.setTime(startDate.getTime() - offset);
  const limit = opts.includeSunday ? 8 : 7;
  for (let dayOfWeek = opts.weekdayOffset; dayOfWeek < limit; dayOfWeek++) {
    result.push(new Date(startDate.getTime() + (dayOfWeek * DAY_IN_MILLIS)));
  }
  return result;
};

const today = new Date();

console.log(`Day of week: ${today.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
  weekday: 'long'
})}`);

// Today to Sunday
console.log(getDatesForCurrentWeek(today, {
  weekdayOffset: today.getDay(),
  includeSunday: true
}));

// All dates for current week
console.log(getDatesForCurrentWeek(today, {
  startOfWeek: true
}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Adding days by adding 24 hours is flawed in places that observe daylight saving and not all days are 24 hours long. See [*Add days to JavaScript Date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date) or any of the [many similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+add+day+to+a+date).